# Getting wrong location name from Google API

Tags: google-maps, google-api

I am using  Google API to Get Locations from Zip Codes, I am using below code 
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=110001&sensor=true,
In the above code I am searching for zipcode 110001 which is zipcode of Delhi, but google is showing this zipcode[110001] is of Singapore.
Did anyone face the same problem?

Comment: That result is in the [response](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=110001&sensor=true) (the second result, at least for me).  How are you parsing it?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Google Geocoding requests are biased based on IP from which the request is sent. If you want to return request from India or some other country, just add `region` parameter to your request. in your case add `&region=in` so your request would look like this:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=110001&region=in&sensor=true
```

For more information on region biasing read ["Region Biasing" section of documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#RegionCodes).